# Foursquare Java API v2 - Checkin Example

Tags: java, foursquare, checkin

I'm trying to create a Foursquare application using its Java API v2 but I couldn't find any sample source code for the checkin process. I don't need to full source code (authentication, venue search, etc), I just need to checkin part.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: i think that you can find one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972477/foursquare-api-and-java

Comment: Thanks but this example uses the version 1 of the API and it's no longer supported by Foursquare.

Comment: link guessing :) https://github.com/wareninja/foursquare-wrapper-for-android/blob/master/src/com/wareninja/android/commonutils/foursquareV2/FoursquareHttpApiV2.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class HelloCheckin {
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    // Construct data
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("ll", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("53.576317,0.113386", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("venueId", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("4e144a2cc65bedaeefbb824a", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("oauth_token", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("YOUR_OAUTHTOKEN", "UTF-8");

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process line...
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}

} }
```

The body of this code came from [Simple Java Post](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html)

Comment: but its generating exception :-12-29 12:21:07.425: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add/
org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnec
tionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
 org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:253)